# Traversing an object and picking out key/value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to create arrays from an keys in an object. I might have an object in this structure:

```
 $scope.myobj = {
 'level1': {
    'level1Sub1': {
        'result': 'level1-level1Sub1-result'
    },
    'level1Sub2': {
          'result': 'level1-level1Sub2-result'
    }
  },
 'level2': {
    'level2Sub1': {
        'result': 'level2-level2Sub1-result'
    },
    'level2Sub2': {
          'result': 'level2-level2Sub2-result'
    }
  }
  }
```

Elements on the same level goes in the same array.
So in this case the result should be:

```
TopLevelArr = [level1, level2]

SecondLevelArr = [level1Sub1, level1Sub2,level2Sub1,level2Sub2]
```

Im using jquery to traverse the whole object:

```
var path = "";

$.each($scope.myobj, walker);

function walker(key, value) {
    var savepath = path;

    path = path ? (path + "." + key) : key;
    console.log(path)


    if (value !== null && typeof value === "object") {
        // Recurse into children
        $.each(value, walker);
    }

    path = savepath;
}
```

This should be pretty close if I could find a way to pass the key into the proper array based on its level.

http://jsfiddle.net/bald1/ys05m1s8/2/

Help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Look into [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)...

Comment: Do level++; $.each(); level--; than level should contain the number you need...

Comment: do you only need 2 levels all the time?

Comment: Thank you all. 
@charlietfl There will always be the same number of levels. I simplified it a bit in the example. The real one will have around 5 levels. So always the same number of levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a iterative and recursive approach for getting all keys.

```js
function getKeys(o) {
    function iter(o, i) {
        var k = Object.keys(o);
        keys[i] = keys[i] || [];
        k.forEach(function (kk) {
            if (keys[i].indexOf(kk) < 0) {
                keys[i].push(kk);
            }
            if (o[kk] !== null && typeof o[kk] === 'object') {
                iter(o[kk], i + 1);
            }
        });
    }

    var keys = [];
    iter(o, 0);
    return keys;
}

var $scope = {};
$scope.myobj = { 'level1': { 'level1Sub1': { 'result': 'level1-level1Sub1-result' }, 'level1Sub2': { 'result': 'level1-level1Sub2-result' } }, 'level2': { 'level2Sub1': { 'result': 'level2-level2Sub1-result' }, 'level2Sub2': { 'result': 'level2-level2Sub2-result' } } };

console.log(getKeys($scope.myobj));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var level=0;
var levelarray=[];
function looptrough(obj){
for(key in obj){
if(typeof obj[key]=="object"){
level++;
looptrough(obj[key]);
level--;
}
levelarray[level]=levelarray[level] || {};
levelarray[level][key]=obj[key];
}
}
looptrough({a:true;b:{c:true}});
```

Levelarray should now contain:

```
0:{a:true;b:{c:true}}
1:{c:true}
```

I thought using jquery is quite unecessary in that case, thats why i used for in...

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help.